# wp-types - How to allow custom fields to be saved in the revision

Tags: custom-post-types, revisions

I am using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

When I use the revision, it does not saves the custom fields data.
Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CF Revision Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-manager/), a library for this job. See also the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/crowdfavorite/wp-revision-manager). I haven't used it, so I cannot offer code examples.

There is also the very fresh Trac ticket [#20564](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20564) where Alex is asking to get this functionality into the core.